# How to completely uninstall Sun Java

Tags: 11.10, java, uninstall, openjdk

I have followed a tutorial on how to install sun jdk manually on ubuntu 11.10, alright it worked. But now I want to remove it, because I want to install the 32bit version instead of the 64 (what I did), can anyone help me.

the tutorial I did: http://www.printandweb.ca/2011/12/install-oracle-jdk-6-for-ubuntu-1110.html

sorry for my english

Comment: Why Sun's Java?

Comment: I need the sun jdk for my work :).

Comment: You should normally install from the software repository. However, Suns-Java has recently been discussed and left the repo, so it is now an exception. But for other packages, allways try synaptic/apt-get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are my notes for installing Oracle JDK6.

Delete the `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6` folder. Download the 32-bit version and follow the same steps.